# Why does removing assumptions change the behaviour of the induction tactic?

Tags: coq, coq-tactic

I am trying to show that the [various definitions of the reflexive-transitive closure](https://coq.github.io/doc/master/stdlib/Coq.Relations.Relation_Operators.html) are equivalent. Here is code that works:

```
Require Import Coq.Relations.Relation_Definitions.
Require Import Coq.Relations.Relation_Operators.

Hint Constructors clos_refl_trans.
Hint Constructors clos_refl_trans_1n.

Lemma clos_refl_trans_1n_right:
  forall {A: Type} {R: relation A} (x y: A), 
    clos_refl_trans A R x y -> clos_refl_trans_1n A R x y.
Proof.
  intros A R x y H.
  induction H as [ | | x y z _ IH1 _ IH2]; eauto.
  induction IH1; eauto.
Qed.
```

Note the underscores denoting thrown away variables. If I give those variables names, the automation fails:

```
Lemma clos_refl_trans_1n_right:
  forall {A: Type} {R: relation A} (x y: A),
    clos_refl_trans A R x y -> clos_refl_trans_1n A R x y.
Proof.
  intros A R x y H.
  induction H as [ | | x y z H1 IH1 H2 IH2]; eauto.
  induction IH1; eauto. (* three subgoals left *)
Fail Qed.
```

Upon examination, we find that the inner induction hypotheses are weaker in the second example. It looks like the induction tactic is detecting a behind-the-scenes dependency between the problematic assumptions and the object of the inner induction.

Is this documented anywhere? What's the rationale, and how can I predict that it will happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that basically it will make your induction hypothesis depend on all the assumptions that are linked to the thing you induct on.
If you do induction on `x : P n m` in a context where you have `h : Q n` and `y : h = h'` it will probably include them in the mix.
In a lot of cases this does not correspond to what you want and doing some `clean` beforehand might make your induction suddenly go through.

There is also a very useful variant of `induction`, `induction ... in` which allows you to specify what part of the context you want to keep when doing the induction.

```
Lemma clos_refl_trans_1n_right:
  forall {A: Type} {R: relation A} (x y: A),
    clos_refl_trans A R x y -> clos_refl_trans_1n A R x y.
Proof.
  intros A R x y H.
  induction H as [ | | x y z H1 IH1 H2 IH2]; eauto.
  induction IH1 in z, IH2 |- *. all: eauto.
Qed.
```

Here you get a warning that I don't really understand to be honest (`Cannot remove x` and `Cannot remove y`) but you get the expected result.
This also has the advantage that it lets you specify what should be generalised.

Maybe someone has a better explanation though.